# PWA Background GeoLocation for WEB

Tags: reactjs, expo, geolocation, progressive-web-apps

I'm creating a PWA with expo and react native.
I would like to capture the mobile site user's latitude and longitude in the background. Is it possible to do this with any expo or react native libraries?

i try to use 'expo-location' but it stops in the background after a few minutes:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getPermissions = async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        console.log('Por favor conceda permissão de acesso')
        return;
      }
      setInterval(async () => {
        let currentPosition = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
        setLocation(currentPosition);
        //console.log('Location:')
        //console.log(currentPosition)
        var posicao = {
          token: '123',
          lat: currentPosition.coords.latitude,
          lon: currentPosition.coords.longitude,
          dtLocalizacao: new Date(currentPosition.timestamp)
        }
        const response = await getDataUsingGet(posicao)
      }, 2000)
    };
    getPermissions();
  }, []);
```